# display php code in header using wp_head()

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

hey i am developing a plugin and i am almost near to close the plugin but i am facing a small problem in displaying the code  `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` below the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the header. i tried using echo but no use it is displaying in string rather of code. below is the code i tried to display:

```
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );
function my_facebook_tags() {
echo '<?php global $options; 
$options = get_option("p2h_theme_options") ?>';
}
```

thanks in advance for help..

Answer (score 0):

You can't just echo it there, you need to return it to your action. Also you can't just echo php code this would just place the php code itself in the output and not execute it. Something like this should work:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );

function my_facebook_tags() {
  global $output
  $output = get_option("p2h_theme_options");
}
```

assuming that whatever is your option is the code that you want to have in the header

Comment: thanks #helmi but its not working..

Comment: I would really like to help you further but "it's not working" is not enough information, sorry.

Comment: Actually i want to display whole code as it is `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` using functions in the plugin. the code which you provided is not at all displaying the code. the output from your code is `$output`. and sorry @Helmi

Comment: you cannot "display" php code. That's why i changed your output. Additionally the code that you are trying to "display" wouldn't display anything.

Comment: so is it possible to display a php code inside a php code??

Comment: you fault in understanding seems to be that php codes normally don't display at all. php code gets executed and if it uses "echo" or something else that is intended to output something then this is "displayed" but actually php code is not supposed to be displayed at all. You could doesn't seem to me as it would display something. It just gets an option value from the wp options table and puts it in the $option variable. There's nothing to display there. You should be more detailled about what you are planning to do, otherwise helping you out is difficult.

Comment: i have clearly mentioned i am developing a plugin where i want to display the above code in header if it displays then my plugin works otherwise it will not work actually when i insert the code manually it is working but i want to be auto after installation that code should display in the header. `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` this code executes using global function from the plugin to get my output of plugin. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, looks like we have a different understanding of "display". I have just modified my answer. This way your code gets executed in the ´<head>´section of the _frontend_ of your site. It's executing your exact code and should work the same way as entering it manually within the ´<head>´.

Comment: the above code will not display the code because there is no such tag applied in the function to display in the `head` here you are just saying `$output = get_option("p2h_theme_options");` but where is the execution part

Comment: the execution of the function containing your code is happening through add_action() - that's how it works in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you wish to print content from get_option below . For that please write below code to funcitons.php file:

```
function my_facebook_tags() {
    return  $options = get_option("p2h_theme_options");
}
```

And below code within your header file below to wp_head() write:

```
<?php echo my_facebook_tags();?>
```

Hope this will resolve the issue for you!

**EDITED**:

Try the below code . It should output the desired result automatically in your header.

```
function my_facebook_tags() {
    echo get_option("p2h_theme_options");
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags');
```

Comment: thanks @shrikant  if inserting this code `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` in the header below `wp_head()` it works i know that but i want the above code to be displayed  auto after installing the plugin rather of coding it manually

Comment: @PullataPraveen: So you basicaly wanted to output data from `get_option("p2h_theme_options");` below to `wp_head()`

Comment: @PullataPraveen: Try the edited code. It should provide you the desired result

Comment: the same code is what i tried and mentioned above in the question. it displays but  is not displaying as code it is showing in the form comment

Comment: @PullataPraveen: Do you want to output the entire code as string. If so then try to replace '<?php' with &lt;php and '?>' to ?&gt;.

Comment: i dont want display it as a string it should be displayed in php code not as a string. can you tell me is it possible to display a php code inside a php function??  but not as a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43336/discussion-between-shrikant-d-and-pullata-praveen).